# Class Symbol FirebaseInstanceIdService [FCM android]

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

anyone can help me to fix this error

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceIdService

I alredy added this to gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
```

my InstanceIDService.java

```
import com.queivera.mannapro.data.SharedPref;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


    private SharedPref sharedPref;

    @Override
    public void onNewToken() {
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        sharedPref.setFcmRegId(token);
        sharedPref.setOpenAppCounter(SharedPref.MAX_OPEN_COUNTER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be extending `FirebaseMessagingService` instead of `FirebaseInstanceIdService`:

```
public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
```

to

```
public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
```

Comment: when i change this : 
public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

to this :
public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

i must be delete  this:
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FcmInstanceIDService;

to this :
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

and new error show

Comment: Remove the old import: import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

Comment: when i remove old import, new error show  https://ibb.co/CB0jPdP

Comment: This error is unrelated to the question you asked. It looks like you're trying to fetch some kind of an old/deprecated Android component. If my answer helped solve the original question, please mark it as accepted and create a new question for the other issue if you cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

```
private SharedPref sharedPref;

@Override
public void onNewToken() {
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    sharedPref.setFcmRegId(token);
    sharedPref.setOpenAppCounter(SharedPref.MAX_OPEN_COUNTER);
}
```

}

Comment: This is not related to my code provided just remove that import